# What's the point of throwing an Exception from the main method of Java program?

Tags: java, exception, program-entry-point

What's the point of throwing an Exception from the main method of Java program,
because it can't ever get caught and handled by any calling method?

the following doesn't really make sense right?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ReconToolException {

    parseCmdArgs(args); 

    try {
        CSVSingleton.tryToReadBothFiles(FILE1_PATH, FILE2_PATH);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    run();

}
```

it would be better as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        parseCmdArgs(args); 

        try {
            CSVSingleton.tryToReadBothFiles(FILE1_PATH, FILE2_PATH);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        try {
            run();
        } catch (ReconToolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

should Java prevent us from doing the former? Or maybe in more complex frameworks the main method has the ability to throw an Exception further up the chain?

Comment: Throwing an exception from `main()` will print the stacktrace without any extra code. This means that the behavior of both examples is identical. The first one is a lot less typing.

Comment: what makes you think it isn't caught?  the jre itself catches it.  And it is a public method, any other code could wrap it and call it and catch it as well.

Comment: no....you can't wrap code around the main method !

Answer (score 1):

Not only can the thrown exception be caught, but those from tryToReadBothFiles ARE caught.

If you are asking about why there is a 'throws' keyword on the main method, I would assume that parseCmdArgs can throw ReconToolException, and the writer of this main either knows it will never be thrown, or doesn't want to handle it. In order to make the program compile he has to do one of two things: add a 'catch' for the exception, or a 'throws' to main. If the program is going to terminate anyway, it doesn't matter which he does. Adding the 'throws' is less work.

Comment: you say it IS caught, but it is not caught in the former. right?

Comment: Exceptions from tryToReadBothFiles are caught. Exceptions from parseCmdArgs are not. Since I didn't know which you were talking about, I covered both.

Comment: right, so I think you might be failing to recognize my question, which is asking what the point of throwing an exception from the main method, the entry point of a Java program, because there is nothing to catch it. it should be disallowed.

Comment: It's in the second paragraph.

Comment: seems like poor design "writer of this main either knows it will never be thrown, or doesn't want to handle it", you never know for sure, and something should be forced to handle it. Someone else mentioned that with Java, if an Exception is bubbled up all the way to main, it will print it out by default. So Java knows to do something. The point is, it's a special case, that needs special attention.

Comment: The author may be happy with the default behaviour.

Comment: `you never know for sure` Actually you can know for sure. If documentations states when something will throw an exception, and you check before calling it, then it will only throw an exception if the method is bugged. In which case you're not equipped to handle the error anyway. In some programs you simply want to crash on certain exceptions. Why handle it yourself when you can let the JVM handle it for you?